# Transformation is moving all my images to the beginning

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgaffinetransform

I have a View with 4 uiimages inside, 1 of them is static, but the other 3 can move, change size and flip horizontal, I can move the images as I want, but the problem is that when I want  to change the size or flip one image, all changes I made before are back to normal. this is my code where I change the size, using a slider

```
- (IBAction)sizePhoto:(UISlider *)sender {

switch (cambiaSize) {
    case 1:
        [_imagen1 setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(sender.value, sender.value)];
        break;
    case 2:
        [_imagen2 setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(sender.value, sender.value)];
        break;
    case 3:
        [_imagen3 setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(sender.value, sender.value)];
        break;
}

}
```

and this is how i flip the images

```
- (IBAction)flipPhonto:(id)sender {

switch (cambiaSize) {
    case 1:
        if (boton1flip == true) {
            _imagen1.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(_photo.transform,1.0, 1.0);
            boton1flip = false;
        }else{
            _imagen1.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(_photo.transform,-1.0, 1.0);
            boton1flip = true;
        }

        break;
    case 2:
        if (boton2flip == true) {
            _imagen2.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(_photo.transform,1.0, 1.0);
            boton2flip = false;
        }else{
            _imagen2.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(_photo.transform,-1.0, 1.0);
            boton2flip = true;
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        if (boton3flip == true) {
            _imagen3.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(_photo.transform,1.0, 1.0);
            boton3flip = false;
        }else{
            _imagen3.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(_photo.transform,-1.0, 1.0);
            boton3flip = true;
        }
        break;
}}
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong, how can I maintain all previous changes when I flip o change size?

Answer (score 0):

turn off autolayout 
you can find it by first clicking on the viewcontroller and then on the file inspector.
There will be a box which should be unticked.